# creating a selection menu with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I would like to know how to make a selection menu as shown in the image (when pressed, the text of the selected menu item is repainted into another one)
[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF82d.png)

Comment: I'm not getting the question well, you can check [ExpansionTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) , `DropDownMenuItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Column to layout that type of view, with a selector for every child.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Column(
   children: [
     GestureDetector(
       onTap: (){
         //Take an action like navegate to another route with pressed info
         /*Navigator.push(
               context,
               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const NextRoute(text : 'girl\boy friend')),);*/
       },
       child: Text(
         'girl/boy friend',
       ),
     ),
     Divider(),
      Text(
       'Just friend',
     ),
     Divider(),
      Text(
       'Mother/father',
     ),
   ],
 );
}
}
```

[Result of that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2K29.png)

Answer (score 0):

From what I am able to understand, I believe you'll need to use action sheets.

The flutter framework comes bundled with a material and a Cupertino action sheet -

- [`CupertinoActionSheet`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoActionSheet-class.html)
- [`BottomSheet`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html)